# RewriteRule, to give a parameter a path

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

sorry If it's a common question, I need a specific answer :

I want to rewrite a url like :

```
/foo/foo0.php?img=foo1/foo2/foo3/bar.jpg
```

into this :

```
/foo/foo1/foo2/foo3/bar.jpg
```

Comment: What server are you using? What have you tried?

Comment: @PPvG `RewriteRule ^foo/(.*/.*/.*/.*)$ foo/foo0.php?img=$1`
doesn't work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ $1/foo0.php?img=$2/$3/$4/$5 [L]
```

Will do it

**EDIT**

Judging from the code you've added you actually want to do it like this:

```
RewriteRule ^foo/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ foo/foo0.php?img=$1/$2/$3/$4 [L]
```

Comment: Should ? is that a common use ?
Is that correct ? `RewriteRule ^foo/(.*/.*/.*/.*)$ foo/bar0.php?img=$1`

Comment: Sorry poor choice of words, I just meant it was untested. As far as I'm aware this is about as common as it gets for a rewrite rule

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments, I don't think the multiple segments are really needed. This should be enough:

```
RewriteRule ^foo/(.*)$ foo/foo0.php?img=$1 [L]
```

This will allow you to use any number of `foo` segments.

Comment: is that secure for my server ?

Comment: Probably no less secure than the other solution, given that they're both allowing all (valid) characters. Of course, you should sanitize any and all user input anyway.